# Are List Int and List String the same category in Haskell/Category theory?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

Are List Int and List String the same category in Haskell/Category theory?

- List Int
- List String

Both are List.

Are they considered the same category?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No -- or rather, mu. Without further details about what you intend the objects and arrows to be, neither of them is a category in the first place.

What you are probably thinking of is the category Hask, which treats Haskell types as objects and Haskell functions as arrows. In this category, `[Int]` and `[String]` are distinct objects, with no (natural, in the non-technical sense of the word) isomorphism between them.

Comment: Thanks. I agree to `Int` and `String` are distinct objects. So what about `List` for both? I'd like to keep reading of your opinion.

Comment: `List` is a type constructor, of kind `* -> *`. When you apply it to either `Int` or `String`, you get back another type (thing of kind `*`), which simply doesn't have a name of its own  in normal usage. We just refer to each by the action of `List` on the underlying type.

Comment: @bayesian-study My statement is the same, whether you use the notation `[Int]` or `List Int`: `List Int` and `List String` are distinct objects, with no obvious isomorphism between them.

Comment: Thanks @chepner Daniel Wagner

Answer (score 2):

In addition to each type being an object in **Hask** (the category of types and functions), each list type can also be thought of as a distinct category, since they are monoids:

1. The category contains a single dummy object; it doesn't represent anything other than as an end point for the morphisms.
2. Each list corresponds to a distinct morphism.
3. The identity morphism is the empty list `[]`.
4. Composition corresponds to list concatenation `(++)`. For example:

   1. `[1] ∘ [2,3] == [1] ++ [2,3] == [1,2,3]`
   2. `[2,3] ∘ [1] == [2,3] ++ [1] == [2,3,1]`
   3. `[] ∘ [1] == [] ++ [1] == [1]`
   4. `[1] ∘ [] == [1] ++ [] == [1]`

Comment: there's still a typo in #2. :)

Comment: Thank you for another detailed answer! @chpner Very informative.